# why is the limit $0$ to $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Could someone explain to me why the limit of this triple integral is $0$ to $\sqrt{2}$?

$\iiint_Q z d v$ where $Q$ is the solid between $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $z = \sqrt{4 - x^2 -y^2}$.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to make much sense: your integration solid is what is between those two cones. What limit of that triple integral?

Comment: i was expecting the limit to be from 0 to 2, not 0 to sqrt of 2.

Comment: @cf What limit in the world are you talking about??

Answer (score 5):

The cone and the upper hemisphere meet at points where $x^2+y^2 = 4-x^2-y^2\implies x^2+y^2 = 2 \implies r^2 = 2 \implies r = \sqrt{2}$. Observe that $\rho = 2$ as you are in spherical coordinates. To get the full set up for the volume, you focus on finding the limits of the spherical angle $\phi$, and $z= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ translates to $\rho\cos \phi = \rho\sin \phi\implies \tan(\phi) = 1\implies \phi = \dfrac{\pi}{4}\implies V = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{0}^2 \rho^2\sin \phi d\rho d\phi d\theta$. If you insist on staying in the cylindrical coordinates, then the set up would utilize $\sqrt{2}$ as you asked for earlier, and again the set up in cylindrical coordinates is: $V = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{r}^{\sqrt{4-r^2}} rdzdrd\theta$.

Comment: The OP cannot properly express himself, and you already used notation from cylindrical and/or spherical coordinates. It looks like a long shot...